# The second function(guess( )) dosent run by click event

Tags: javascript, html, function, event-handling, mouseclick-event

Im trying to write a guess number app. it contains two function, the first which is startGame() works properly(receive the max number and then dissapear by taking the hidden class). but the second one which is suppose receive the users guess and check the users guess with the target number to see if they are equal dosent work. Heres the html and javascript source code.

````
const stage2 = document.getElementById('stage2');
const maximuminput = document.getElementById('maximum');
const startbutton = document.getElementById('start');
const guessinput = document.getElementById('guess-number');
const guessbutton = document.getElementById('guess-button');
const chancesspan = document.getElementById('chances');


let maximumNumber, totalChances, targetNumber;

startbutton.addEventListener('click', startGame);
function startGame(){
  maximumNumber = Number(maximuminput.value);

  if(maximumNumber > 10) {
      targetNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximumNumber + 1));
      totalChances = Math.floor(Math.log2(maximumNumber)) + 1;
      chancesspan.textContent = totalChances;
      stage1.classList.toggle('hidden');
      stage2.classList.toggle('hidden');
  }else {
      const p = document.querySelector('#stage1 p');
      p.outerHTML = '<P class="red">عدد وارد شده باید بزرگتر از 10 باشد</P>'
  }
}

guessbutton.addEventListener('click', guess);

function guess(){
  let yourguess = NUmber(guessinput.value);
  if(yourguess == targetNumber){
      stage2.innerHTML = '<p class="blue">تبریک شما موفق شدید</p>';
      return;

  }else if(yourguess > targetNumber) {
      const status = document.getElementById('status');
      status.innerHTML += `<span class="red">${yourguess}</span>`;
  }else {
      const status = document.getElementById('status');
      status.innerHTML += `<span class="red">${yourguess}</span>`;
  }

  remainingChances = Number(chancesspan.textContent);
  remainingChances -- ;
  if(remainingChances > 0 ){
      chancesspan.textContent = remainingChances;
  }else {
      stage2.innerHTML = '<p class="red>!متاسفانه فرصت شما به پایان رسید</p>"'
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a typo here

`let yourguess = NUmber(guessinput.value);`

`let yourguess = Number(guessinput.value);`